# Matplotlib - How to get data from surface plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to get X, Y and Z data back from a surface plot (Poly3DCollection), generated by `Axes3D.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xdata, ydata, zdata, _ = ax.collections[0]._vec
```

Change the index to the correct value if you are plotting multiple surfaces.
As far as I know, it is not possible to update these values.